# Scala - How to get type info from Abstract Syntax Tree in Scala reflection

Tags: scala, reflection, abstract-syntax-tree

I'd like to get **type information** from Abstract Syntax Tree in Scala reflection.

Eventually, I'd like to convert Scala code into other programming language.

For example,

Scala code

```
{
    val s = "hello, world"
    val d = 10
}
```

Converted other language code

```
begin
   string s :=  "hello, world";
   int d :=  10;
   return ();
end
```

For creating this converter, I have to get **type information** inferred by Scala.

I created uncompleted a converter. 
The following code is the uncompleted converter.

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

val exp = reify(
  {
    val s = "hello, world"
    val d = 10
  }
)

// convert exp.tree
println(convert(exp.tree))


// Definition of the Converter
def convert(tree: Tree): String = tree match {
  // convert "val d = 10" to "int d := 10"
  case ValDef(modifiers, variableName, typeTree, rightSide) =>
    s"[variable type] ${variableName} :=  ${convert(rightSide)};"

  /*
      {
       statementA
       statementB
      }

      into

      begin
        statementA;
        return statementB;
      end
   */
  case Block(codeList, returnValue) =>
    s"""begin
      |${codeList
        .map(convert)    // convert
        .map("    " + _) // indent
        .mkString("\n")}
      |    return ${returnValue};
      |end
      |
    """.stripMargin

  // for example,
  // Literal(Constant("hello, world") into "hello, world"
  case Literal(Constant(any)) =>
    any match {
      case _: String => "\"" + any + "\""
      case _         => any.toString
    }

  // unimplemented, unexpected or unknown tree format
  case tree =>
      "Unknown tree " + showRaw(tree)
 }
```

The output is the following

```
begin
    [variable type] s :=  hello, world;
    [variable type] d :=  10;
    return ();
end
```

I couldn't get **type information**. I want to fill `[variable type]` with `string` or `int`.

Could you tell me how to get type information from Abstract Syntax Tree?

Comment: Google `ToolBox` to `typecheck` a tree. Then `tree.tpe`. Ppl use quasiquotes to make trees.

Comment: Thank you for your response.
import scala.tools.reflect.ToolBox and
import scala.reflect.runtime.{currentMirror=>cm} and 
cm.mkToolBox().typecheck(exp.tree). it works!